# Intuition for Monty Hall and a similar problem

Tags: probability, self-learning, monty-hall

Recently I was doing a problem that I thought might be similar to the Monty Hall problem. In it were five intervals $\left[0,2\right], \ \left[2,10\right], \ \left[10,30\right], \ \left[30,70\right], \ \left[70,90\right] $ in which a person could die. The person could choose an interval to die in uniformly, so the probability of any interval being chosen is $0.2$. Suppose a person lived till $30$, then the probability of death is now $1$ over the remaining two intervals, so he can choose either of them with probability $0.5$.

All correct till this stage (I hope). Now replace this with the Monty Hall doors. The first three doors have been eliminated, so the probability of "winning" is $1$ over the remaining two doors.

Do I switch? It seems no, but the answer is yes, as we know. I've been thinking of why. It's because the two problems aren't really the same at all. The event "dying" isn't pre-determined to be in any interval -- it occurs with probability $1$ in any of the intervals that are still remaining. Whereas, the car's position is pre-determined -- no matter what, the car is always behind a door (which will never be opened by the host before he asks his question). In other words, the car isn't randomly spread over two doors -- it's located for sure behind a single door.

Said another way, the conditional probablity of death in the remaining intervals is $1$, while the conditional probability of the car being in the door we didn't choose is $2/3$, because that's the nature of the variables we're dealing with.

Is this a correct intuition for these problems? Can someone give a more formal/less rambling explanation?

Comment: Another difference between this and Monty Hall is that you knew beforehand which doors would be revealed, regardless of which door hides the "price" (i.e. dying).

Comment: Consider an alternative to the Monty Hall problem where, before your initial selection, Monty decides at random which non-prize door to open later, whether or not you pick it initially.  Then when that door is opened, all the non-open doors have an increase in the probability in having the prize (including the one you pick initially, if not the opened door).

Comment: @Henry In other words, I can pick only one of two things here, hence $0.5$, right?

Actually, why does this matter in the original Monty Hall problem? Why isn't winning just spread over the two doors? Could you give a better explanation than I have up there?

Comment: You should choose the intervals in a way that they do not share a common number, "$30$ years" could be interval $3$ or $4$

Comment: @Peter Not my question, but I agree!

Comment: Not necessarily $0.5$ if the initial events did not have equal probability.  But you do have $P(30 \le X \lt 70 \mid X \ge 30)=\dfrac{P(30 \le X \lt 70)}{P(30 \le X \lt 70)+P(X \ge 70)}$

Comment: @learning What exactly is the question ? The intuition behind the Monty-Hall-problem or whether this problem can be tackled in a similar way ?

Comment: @Peter My question, I guess, would be how these two problems are related. Henry gave a good way to think about it, but I would love to see another explanation. Why does eliminating after we choose matter in the original Monty Hall problem? The conditional probability of winning is still $1$ over the remaining two doors, but it's no longer a uniform distribution. Why? The "death" problem can be visualised as having a reduced sample space after conditioning, and then we impose a uniform distribution over this. Why not with Monty Hall?

Comment: Why does reducing the sample space _after_ we choose matter?

Comment: @learning To explain the Monty-Hall-problem. No matter whether you change your decision or not, the probability that you initially choose the door with the car , is $\frac{1}{3}$. Since it is always possible to open a door without the car that was not chosen, the opening door does not change the probability that your initial choice was good (car). The advantage of changing is just the fact that you will win the car when you change, whenever you initially chose the wrong door. If you do not change, you only win when you initially chose the right door.

Comment: @Peter Ah! So it comes down to (as I said, maybe not too clearly, in the question), that death is still a random thing that hasn't occurred, but the car is a constant fixture behind one of the doors! Is this right? So, it relates very clearly to "choice hasn't been made yet" and "choice has been made", except the choices aren't by the humans, but by "death" and "car".

Comment: That seems to make sense.

Comment: Thanks to everyone!